# Multipeer Connectivity Session Disconnected After Switching VC

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8, multipeer-connectivity

I am currently working on a multipeer connectivity project that contains multiple view controllers. My multipeer connectivity program is in one file and extends other files where I need to interact with buttons ect. I have done a few tests and I have noticed that when I switch view controllers after they have connected, I get some weird errors. I have looked into the console and it says I have 1 peer connection, but when I load the next view controller it says it loaded with 0 peers. I do not get a disconnection notice and it does not say I have lost a peer. Also if I quit the app on one of the devices it says on the other it disconnected only after I close the app. So why is it doing this does anybody have any suggestions. I can post the code if you would like. Thanks.

Also just a general question, is a session meant to reset or disconnect after the VC switch?

Here is the console output:

```
2017-03-20 22:47:12.399 MyProject[44689:1031520] Did send data to 1 peers
2017-03-20 22:47:12.399 MyProject[44689:1031520] Game Started with 1 peers
2017-03-20 22:47:12.420 MyProject[44689:1031439] View loaded with 0 peers
```

Comment: Where do you put those Multipeer objects ?

Comment: All the objects to do with multipeer connectivity are in one file and any file that needs to interact with it calls the class. So any session that is active is communicating from the MPC file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't passing the variables forward to next class when I switched view controllers. The was MCSession variables and other things to do with the connection. Going to a new view controller, I left all the data in the other VC. Refer to this: [Swift 3 - Passing Variables and Functions Between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966582/swift-3-passing-variables-and-functions-between-view-controllers)